# VPN disables network after about 20 minutes

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, openvpn

I've running a Windows 7 guest under VirtualBox. If (and only if) I run a VPN client such as Viscosity or the OpenVPN client, after about 20 minutes, they both stop working and it turns out that my Windows guest has lost complete connectivity (not just DNS, you can't even ping anything via IP address) to the network, even to local LAN.

Quiting the VPN client makes no difference, I find I have to reboot the Windows guest to get it working again.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: you should provide more supporting information in your question, like `tracert google.com` `tracert 8.8.4.4` `ipconfig /all` `route print` before the connectivity problem occur AND after it occur

Comment: Good point --- I've now collected that information but don't see where I can put it since these comments limit one to 5 or 6 hundred characters.

Comment: Can someone please tell me the best way to add the requested information? Is there another website where the data should be posted?